# App crashes when login form submit is pressed (testing with generated APK and installed on device) react-native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, native-base

I got mysterious crash on android app whenever I Click login button inside login form, just simple form with username and password, after click request is being send with axios to verify the user.

When I run the app in emulator - works everything fine, just this crash accouring when app is generated for production as APK file.

Any Ideas what's happening? :?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any available solutions for this problem? I think it has to do something with stack.navigator, because it breakes by the time it reaches that screen with navigator stacks.